# Master Page More has more than one content

Tags: c#, asp.net, master-pages

just now when i was created my master page it gives me this error. The page has one or more asp content that do not correspond withasp content place holder.
What is wrong with my master page? Here is my code of master page. Thank you.

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="MasterPage.master.cs"   
 Inherits="MasterPage" %>

 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0
 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head runat="server">
 <title>Master</title>
 <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="head" runat="server">
 </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
 <style type="text/css">
    .style1
    {
        height: 63px;
    }
    .style3
    {
        height: 101px;
        font-size: xx-large;
        font-weight: 700;
        font-family: Tahoma;
        text-align: center;
        color: #FFFFFF;
    }
    .style6
    {
        width: 146px;
        height: 592px;
    }
    .style7
    {
        width: 897px;
        height: 592px;
    }
    .style8
    {
        height: 592px;
    }
    .style9
    {
        font-size: small;
        height: 101px;
        border-left-color: #808080;
        border-right-color: #C0C0C0;
        border-top-color: #808080;
        border-bottom-color: #C0C0C0;
        background-color: #996633;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <table style="width: 100%; height: 623px; margin-bottom: 0px;">
        <tr>
            <td bgcolor="#996633" class="style3" colspan="3">
                Malaysia Car Booking System<br />
                <span class="style9">Your satisfaction is our Priority</span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td bgcolor="#CC6600" class="style6">
            </td>
            <td bgcolor="#FF9900" class="style7" style="vertical-align: top">
                <asp:PlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolder1" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
            </td>
            <td bgcolor="#CC6600" class="style8">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td bgcolor="#996633" class="style1" colspan="3">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
      </div>
     </form>
     </body>
     </html>
```

Comment: Did you read the message? What don't you understand?

Answer (score 3):

What's wrong is that you have a `Content` tag in your content page that doesn't have a corresponding `ContentPlaceHolder` tag in the master page.

The only `ContentPlaceHolder` tag in the master page is in the head tag. It is quite uncommon to not have any in the body tag, as it makes it hard to introduce any body content from the content page. You have a `PlaceHolder` tag in the body that you perhaps meant to be a `ContentPlaceHolder` tag?

Answer (score 2):

It would appear that your page has `<asp:content>` tags which do not correspond to `<asp:ContentPlaceHolder>` controls in your MasterPage.

For this type of solution, master pages never support comments in the format `<!-- -->`

This could be causing your error.

Comment: +1... Thank you man..! I never knew that. Solved my problem.!

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error when I created a very simple master page and let visual studio create a normal page based on that master page. After running the website, the error message disappeared. It seemed like the error message was based on the old master page and that visual studio used the changed master page only for verification once the website was actually run. Strange :-(

Answer (score 0):

You need to include `runat = "server"` in **title** tag most of the time it solve the problem